# Why doesn't tsc run in Heroku?

Tags: typescript, heroku, deployment, tsc

I have a React Express TypeScript app which I've been struggling to deploy to Heroku. The aim is to deploy the app without manually creating the client `build` (React script) and server `dist` (tsc) folders, i.e. those folders should be built during deployment in Heroku. At the moment, the `build` folder is successfully built, but not the `dist` folder. I have double checked this by running the deployed app in bash mode and going through the folders. It seems like tsc  does not run on the server side, but there are no warnings or errors regarding this during deployment.

To give some overview, I have the following folder structure (many folders and files left out for brevity):

```
|-- client
|   |-- public
|   |-- src
|   |-- package.json
|   '-- tsconfig.json
|-- server
|   |-- dist <-- **THIS FOLDER DOES NOT BUILD DURING DEPLOYMENT**
|   |-- src
|   |-- package.json
|   '-- tsconfig.json
'-- package.json
```

My `package.json` file (in the root folder) looks like this:

```
{
  ... ,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/dist/index.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --prefix server && npm install --prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && NODE_ENV=production && npm run tsc --prefix server && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  ... ,
  "engines": { 
    "node": "12.13.1",
    "npm": "6.12.1"
  }
}
```

...and the `server/tsconfig.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

My understanding is that `npm run tsc --prefix server` in `heroku-postbuild` should do the trick, but it doesn't. I am probably missing something here. Maybe my folder structure is not correct, but I feel like that should not be an issue to get the app deployed.

I would be thankful to get any help or pointers to the right direction.

**Edit:**
I should also mention that TypeScript has been add as a dependency in `server/package.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.13",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/socket.io": "^2.1.11",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.34",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jest": "^26.5.3",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.1",
    "supertest": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: You've mixed up the order of flags, you should be using `npm --prefix server run tsc`

Comment: @FalseDev Thanks for your reply. I just tried it and it didn't make any difference. PS If the order of the flags were of importance, the client `build` folder would not have been built. Likewise with the dependency installations in the client and server folders.

Comment: Put this in your build script rather than the `post-build`, post-build doesn't allow file-system modifications and is for things like database migrations

Comment: @FalseDev The Heroku documentation states that if there is a `heroku-postbuild` script, the `build` script will be skipped and the `postbuild` script will run instead. I have also seen this in the build logs. The fact that the `client/build` folder is created in this step also tells me that there is no issue having these commands in the `postbuild` script. To summarize what I'm trying to say here is that it seems to work as it should, apart from the `tsc` command. I can also mention that I previously had the `heroku-prebuild` commands in the `postbuild` script with no issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still haven't managed to find a solution. So I ended up with a workaround.
In case someone is struggling with the same thing, what I did was to run `tsc` manually on the server to create the `server/dist` folder. It is not the solution I was looking for, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in package.json

```
"scripts": {
....//your commands
"tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
....//your commands
},
```

It will run the local 'tsc' command from local Typescript inside node_modules.

PS: I installed Typescript as devDependencies(npm i -D typescript)